# I am facing problems while installing XEN hypervisor on ubuntu11.10 i386

Tags: ubuntu, xen, hypervisor

sudo apt-get install xen-hypervisor-amd64

sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_DEFAULT=.*+/GRUB_DEFAULT="Xen 4.1-amd64"/' /etc/default/grub

sudo update-grub

sudo sed -i 's/TOOLSTACK=.*+/TOOLSTACK="xm"/' /etc/default/xen

[ERROR]sed: can't read /etc/default/xen: No such file or directory

Comment: I manually searched xen folder but it has not been created.

Comment: you can do a `whereis xen` and see.